# How to add logic to my SQL query to include/exclude search parameters?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Using SQL Server 2008R2, I have here is a simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ItemData  
WHERE FREETEXT(Title, '"' + @OriginalSearchTerm + '"')   
AND  ( WebsiteID=@WebsiteID AND GeoCity = @GeoCity  AND GeoState = @GeoState )  
ORDER BY ItemListID DESC
```

This is all fine when there is a valid value for `@GeoCity` and `@GeoState`.  However there will be scenarios where `@GeoCity = -1` and/or `@GeoState = -1`.

I would rather not write entire separate queries for these cases, although this would work just fine.

How can I optimize the current query to do just this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please read the bible on this: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- This might be more efficient as OR statement executes block for each OR statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM ItemData  
WHERE FREETEXT(Title, '"' + @OriginalSearchTerm + '"')   
AND  ( WebsiteID=@WebsiteID AND 
    (GeoCity = ISNULL(@GeoCity,-1)) AND
    (GeoState = ISNULL(GeoState,-1))
ORDER BY ItemListID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want the query to do when `@GeoCity = -1` and/or `@GeoState = -1`. Assuming you want to exclude the `GeoCity = @GeoCity` and/or `GeoState = @GeoState` conditions in that case, here's the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ItemData  
WHERE FREETEXT(Title, '"' + @OriginalSearchTerm + '"')   
AND  ( WebsiteID=@WebsiteID AND 
    (@GeoCity = -1 OR GeoCity = @GeoCity)  AND
    (@GeoState = -1 OR GeoState = @GeoState) )  
ORDER BY ItemListID DESC
```